# less command g vs p option

Tags: command-line, less, options

In `less` for navigation purposes according with this tutorial

- [Less Command in Linux](https://linuxize.com/post/less-command-in-linux/)

indicates:

```
g   Go to the first line in the file.
p   Go to the beginning of the file.
```

I tested both, and of course the result is the same (of course using `G` to go bottom) and testing each one.

But just at a first glance if `g` and `G` do the opposite to each other and they are enough to go to the first line (top) and last line (bottom) respectively - so why there is the `p` option if it does the same as `g`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He, this is mischaracterizing what these commands actually do. `p` is for "percentage".

Try typing `20p` and you'll jump to 20% of the file length. Nifty!

`20g` works too, but it goes to the twentieth line.

Simply typing `g` or `p` just implies `0g` or `0p`; because the zeroth line and the zeroth byte are both the file's beginning, that works out as the same.

You can test this rather easily; I'm assuming you're using `zsh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/zsh
(for i in {1..1000}; echo $i) | less
```

will display 1000 numbered lines, and `33g` will jump to line 33, but `33.3p` will jump to line 333 :)

Answer (score 6):

It says in the `less` help (`less` a file, press `h`) that you can go to the percent mark of the file with `p`. For example, you can do `50p` in the `less` prompt and it will go to the 50% point (halfway point) of the file. I think the reason why it goes to the start of the file is because you haven't supplied a number (for where to go) before the `p`, so it just goes to the start.

For example:

```
$ less example.txt
```

example.txt:

```
This is the start


This is the middle


This is the end
```

When I do `50p`:

```
This is the middle


This is the end
~
~
~
~
~
~
```

When I do `p`:

```
This is the start


This is the middle


This is the end
~
~
~
~
```

Comment: it is only about the `p` option when less is running or open, it goes to the top or first line, it is **not** about `<number>p`

Comment: @ManuelJordan it definitely is the same command :) so yes, it's about exactly that, `<number>p`.